# MUI: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p> and validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog, mui-x

I have this react code -

```
<Box>    
     <b>Note: </b>Please verify the details before proceeding.        
    <b>Details</b>           
</Box>           
<Box align="center" mt={1}>             
    <Typography>
        Name:<b>{name}</b>             
    </Typography>             
    <Typography>               
        location: <b>{location}</b>             
    </Typography>           
</Box>
```

I have these lines inside DialogContent MUI. The app is working fine but It Throws these following errors in console-

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

I want to fix these errors.

Comment: Can't reproduce.